# How to cast CustomEditText instead of EditText for SearchView?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, searchview

I want to cast internal `SearchView.SearchAutoComplete` to a `CustomEditText` just like this code as we do for `EditText`;

```
SearchView searchView =(SearchView) search_menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search).getActionView();
EditText edtSearch = ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text));
```

I want to customize its background and so on, so the question is how can I cast is to a `CustomEditText`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: share code of `CustomEditText`

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchView searchView =(SearchView) search_menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search).getActionView();
EditText edtSearch = ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text));

if(editSearch instanceof CustomEditText){
CustomEditText customText= (CustomEditText) editSearch;
}
```

*just check if EditText is instance of CustomEditText and typeCast it*

Comment: instanceof function works when CustomEditText is parent of EditText or is something with type of EditText. It doesn't work.

Comment: when you say `CustomEditText` this is your Custom class which is extending EditText class? if not can you share the link/code for `CustomEditText`
@MohsenHatami

Comment: I extended my `CustomEditText` from `EditText` and `AppCompatEditText`, Both are not working

Answer (score 0):

When you take a look at the source code of `SearchView`, you will acknowledge that the default input view is inflating to `R.id.search_src_text`

This is the inflate function:

```
final int layoutResId = a.getResourceId(
            R.styleable.SearchView_layout, R.layout.search_view);
```

This is the layout: `R.layout.search_view`

[image]

So to answer your question, there is no way to custom `EditText` and find it with the function: `findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text));`
because system **cann't map an instance of EditText to an id which already sticked with another view**.

In order to customize `SearchAutoComplete` of `SearchView`, I suggest 4 ways to achieve it:

1. Using [Reflection](https://medium.com/@fredgrott/speed-inflate-those-custom-views-2a405107f4a2) or [Transform API](https://medium.com/grandcentrix/transform-api-a-real-world-example-cfd49990d3e1) to edit the default implementation of SeachView which could be time-consuming and hard to do.
2. Android provide [Search Dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog) to help you implement many features like voice search or suggestion
3. Customize `SearchView` directly, instead of `CustomEditText`
4. I think `SearchView$SearchAutoComplete` of `SearchView` has a well implementation. It provides a lot of event callbacks to cover the use-cases. As your question mentioned, changing background or something else mightnot a big deal. Just get the view and edit it.

[image]